# Problem In getting alien package converter update in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux-distributions, ubuntu-9.04, installation-package, alien

I have to convert a .rpm file into the .deb file to install VMware server into my ubuntu...
I am facing a problem in downlaoding the update...can anyoneone guide me through the process...I tried sudo apt-get update and it is also not updating ....
please can someone help....
it is also not able to download the alien package individually...
It shows the following error msg..

abhimanyu@abhimanyu-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install alien
[sudo] password for abhimanyu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package alien